# Getting this error when calling nftswapv4.fillSignedOrder

Tags: 0x

Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'erc1155Token' in undefined.

maybe the order isn't posting?
Here's the code I'm using to post it:

await nftSdk.postOrder(signedOrder, chainId);

If anyone has run into any similar issues please let me know

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you posted, I'm assuming that you're using the `@traderxyz/nft-swap-sdk`. You can probably get much better support in the [Trader Discord](https://discord.com/invite/RTvpQcxn4V)

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem in Discord together, but wanted to x-post here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

Here's a working sandbox of grabbing all orders from the orderbook (including filtering). https://codesandbox.io/s/orderbook-search-example-ryo418

I believe there was just some small config error of some sort, so following the codesandbox should serve as a sufficient reference to get unblocked. (From there, you can take the queried order(s) and fill them using `nftSdk.fillSignedOrder(signedOrder);`.

And yes, the fastest way to get help with the NFT support using the Swap SDK is the #dev-help channel here:
https://discord.com/channels/879789553060282388/915257624050663495

Thank you!